# pybind11 crashes (segmentation fault (core dumped)) while importing ONNX python module

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, pybind11, onnx

I am using pybind11 in my C++ code. When I try to import `onnx`, my code crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. However, if I import `onnxruntime`, everything is well. Of course both `onnx` and `onnxruntime` are installed on my system via `pip`.

```
// installed libraries
pip install onnx
pip install onnxruntime
```

```
// C++ code
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

py::module::import("onnxruntime"); // This is okay
py::module::import("onnx"); // This crashes with segmentation fault
```

The order of the import lines is irrelevant. Wherever it is, `py::module::import("onnx")` crashes with segmentation fault. How can I successfully run `py::module::import("onnx")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The cause of the problem was that `onnx` was not compatible with `protobuf` version 3.19.0 or higher. Using `protobuf` between 3.18.1 and 3.12.0 will solve the problem.